# How to change desktop environment in Raspbian?

Tags: desktop-environment, lxde, raspberry-pi

I'm running Raspbian “wheezy”, a Debian based Linux distribution for the Raspberry Pi and I would like to know where I can change the desktop environment that boots with the OS.
In particular, how can I replace LXDE with a custom QT or Java program?

Comment: Have you tried using standard Debian tools? As far as I know they should work, the only problem I can think of is I'm almost sure there will be missing packages compared to  i386/x86_64.

Comment: First thing I'd try is placing a [`.xinitrc` file](http://wiki.debian.org/Xinitrc) in the default user's home...

Comment: I have been looking at their documents/forums and as @sr_ suggested they use .xinitrc (located at your home) to exec lxde, so it's just a matter of replacing the line where lxde loads and add your custom program.

Comment: i've found also some info pointing me to .xinitrc but i fail to find that file, tryed on Raspbian “wheezy” and on Ubuntu 12.04 and there is no file with that name

Comment: Can you run `which startx`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to install Raspbian Lite to your Pi and install a different desktop, but this is not recommended because you may have WiFi connectivity problems. You may also be able to install a display manager with support for desktop switching, for example, GDM, then install a desktop. I don't think anyone has tried this before, and it may be extremely dangerous.

Comment: Try to answer with facts, ideally by citing the source. Also, note that the original question is eight years old. Changing the desktop environment is just an `apt-get install` away, without extreme dangers.